# How to not invoke warning: type specifier missing?

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, kernighan-and-ritchie

I am reading "[The C programming Language](https://github.com/mixelpixel/The-C-Programming-Language#the-c-programming-language)" by Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie. In chapter 1.2 "Variables and Arithmetic Expressions" they demonstrate a simple Fahrenheit to Celsius converter program. When I compile the program (Terminal.app, macOS Sierra), I get this warning:

```
$  cc FtoC.c -o FtoC.o
FtoC.c:5:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
main()
^
1 warning generated.
```

This is the C program:

```
FtoC.c:
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 
  3 /* print Fahrenheit-Celsius table
  4     for fahr = 0, 20, ..., 300 */
  5 main()
  6 {
  7   int fahr, celsius;
  8   int lower, upper, step;
  9 
 10   lower = 0;      /* lower limit of temperature scale */
 11   upper = 300;    /* upper limit */
 12   step = 20;      /* step sze */
 13 
 14   fahr = lower;
 15   while (fahr <= upper) {
 16       celsius = 5 * (fahr-32) / 9;
 17       printf("%d\t%d\n", fahr, celsius);
 18       fahr = fahr + step;
 19   }
 20 }
```

If I understand [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34774190/5225057) correctly, this error is the result of non-compliance with the C99 standard. (?)

> The problem is not the compiler but the fact that your code does not follow the syntax. C99 requires that all variables and functions be declared ahead of time. Function and class definitions should be placed in a .h header file and then included in the .c source file in which they are referenced.

How would I write this program with the proper syntax and header information to not invoke this warning message?

For what it is worth, the executable file outputs the expected results:

```
$  ./FtoC.o 
0   -17
20  -6
40  4
60  15
80  26
100 37
120 48
140 60
160 71
180 82
200 93
220 104
240 115
260 126
280 137
300 148
```

---

[This](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm) was useful:

```
return_type function_name( parameter list ) {
   body of the function
}
```

Also [this overview](http://www.electronicdesign.com/dev-tools/what-s-difference-between-c-now-and-then) of K&R C vs C standards, and a [list of C programming books](https://stackoverflow.com/a/562377/5225057), or, for the [C language standards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/83763/5225057).

Comment: Use `int main()` instead of just `main()`. Main should also return an integer value, usually 0 (or `EXIT_SUCCESS` if you include `stdlib.h`).

Comment: Does the linked answer not give you a hint?

Comment: Since you're passing a `-std=c99` flag, I think it will actually try to compile as ansi C (I think that's c89). No c99 issue here. But keep in mind that, while it's good, Kernighan & Ritchie is also old (I don't know if there are updated versions out there for current C standards & compilers); so some things will be, well, archaic.

Comment: Hint: get another book.

Comment: Note: the `.o` extension is usually used for object files. Which is not what you're creating here. Just use `cc FtoC.c -o FtoC`, or even just `cc FtoC.c` and run `./a.out` for simple test programs.

Comment: @InternetAussie I wasn't sure if I should be writing/incorporating `*.h` files and wasn't sure about what `int` meant prior to `main {}` but per Evert's comment, it is for a return value?

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy Yes, it is for a return value. Zero for success, non-zero for failure.

Comment: @Evert thanks for the heads up. Any other C programming books you could recommend?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Is there one you might recommend?

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy In my opinion, K&R is still an excellent book to learn C. Although it is old, it covers the language very well, and teaches you all the basics you need to know.

Comment: Your code is not compilant with C89 standard either. Plain `main()` is not allowed by any C stanard. It is something from K&R C.

Comment: @AnT thank you, that is good to know!

Comment: @HonzaRemeš: K&R apparently does **not** cover the language. C has evolved a lot since K&R and C90 times. Teaching people latin to communication in an english talking country is not really a good idea, although there are a lot of latin phrases in the english language.

Comment: Get a more recent book about modern C. K&R is outdated since 18 years **at least**.

Comment: @Olaf can you recommend a book about modern C? Thanks.

Comment: There is a booklist on SO. How about searching yourself? I never used a book, the standard is sufficient **for me**.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just give `main` a return type:

```
int main()
```

and make sure to add `return 0;` as the last statement.

Comment: In C99 mode you don't even need an explicit `return`.

Comment: `int main(){...return 0;}` ?

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy yup!

Answer (score 5):

You can either tell the compiler to use the C language standard C90 (ANSI), which was modern when the book was written. Do it by using parameter `-std=c90` or `-ansi` to the compiler, like this:

```
cc -ansi FtoC.c -o FtoC.o
```

or you can rewrite the program to adhere to a newer standard (C99), which is what your compiler uses by default, by adding a return type to the `main` function, like this:

```
int main()
```

Comment: Thanks - I do plan on reading the whole book for the fundamnetals and historical value.

Comment: Plain `main()` is not valid in C90 either. C90 does not allow declarations with empty *decl-specifier* sequences.

Comment: @AnT True, but the compilers (at least GCC) usually tolerate it in C90 mode. While it is not a good idea to write production code like this, I think it is OK to use the parameters to silence the compiler when studying example code in a book.

Answer (score 1):

You should give return type for the main function. By default it takes `int` as its return type.

Either try,

```
int main() {
  //.....
return some_int_value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **int main()** the function should return a value i.e. 0

```
int main()
{
 //.....
return 0;
}
```